# Getting user's birthday through Facebook API

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm having some troubles with the Facebook API, I am requesting permission for some information of the user by Javascript:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // authorized
    } else {
        // canceled
    }
}, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location'});
```

Now I want to get the user's information (when he is authorized) by PHP:

```
$facebookUser = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $this->data['userid'] . '?access_token=' . $this->oathtoken . '&fields=id,name,location,gender,email,picture,birthday,link'));
```

All working great, except that the API is not giving the user's birthday back. Even when I set my birthday privacy settings on public it won't show up.

So:

```
echo $facebookUser['birthday']; // Gives an error, since this key does not exists
```

Does somebody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Interesting, the first time I tried, I did get the birthday, but not on subsequent tries for the same user. I looked at Privacy settings and see that app. has privilege to see my birthday, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are logged in on the client side but php is executed on the server side so you receive only the basic information of an user object.

If you logged in on the server side and have the [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) so you can get the birthday simply with:

```
echo $facebookUser['birthday'];
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question though.

Comment: Well, it kinda does. Since he is not using the PHP SDK, but making a simple HTTP request on his own, no access token gets passed. So he either has to pass the token from client- to server-side by himself, or read it out of a cookie, and append it to the request URL himself – or use the SDK, which should handle all of these concerns on it’s own quite nicely.

Comment: I have tried that, but that key does not exists. So it seems I have not the permission to view it. Although I am requesting it...

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you didn't receive approval to request `user_birthday` from FB.

You can't get `user_birthday` unless FB reviews your FB app.

Only the following permissions may be requested without review: `public_profile`, `user_friends` and `email`
(See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review)

Without review you can request only `age_range`, but not `user_birthday`

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    var user_birthday = response.user_birthday; 
    console.log(user_birthday);
if (response.authResponse) {

} else {
    // canceled
}
}, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location'});
```

why don't you use serverside auth if you would like get FB info in server side? 
if you are ok with clientside authentication, above should work.

Comment: I am saving information in a database, and didn't want to do an extra AJAX call. That's why I used it server side. I have tried your idea, but `response.user_birthday` is `undefined` when the callback is executed.